# Separate codes for separate touches

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a SKNode, and when I touch it, under touches began, it runs this code:

```
if node.name == "0.5" { 
node.name = "test" 
node.fillColor = UIColor(hue: 1.0, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0) print(node.name) 
} else if node.name == "test" { 
node.name = "0.5" 
node.fillColor = UIColor(hue: 0.4, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0) }
```

The above code should change the Node from blue to red and back to blue with each touch on it.
It came back saying "optional "test"" so it is registering the name change and color change, but when I click on it again, it doesn't change color again? Why?

Thanks

Comment: How do you implement `touchesBegan`?

Comment: And `SKNode`doesn't have `fillColor` property. Did you mean `SKShapeNode`?

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at my touches began. Part of the code was stopping it from working. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do what you want :

```
if node.name == "0.5" {
   node.name = "test"
   node.fillColor = UIColor(hue: 1.0, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 
} else if node.name == "test" {
  node.name = "0.5"
  node.fillColor = UIColor(hue: 0.5, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Using a Switch case might be a good idea if you start having more than two possible node names.

Comment: if node.name == "0.5" {
                        node.name = "test"
                        node.fillColor = UIColor(hue: 1.0, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
                        print(node.name)
                    } else if node.name == "test" {
                        node.name = "0.5"
                        node.fillColor = UIColor(hue: 0.4, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
                    }

It came back saying "optional "test"" so it is registering the name change and color change, but when I click on it again, it doesn't change color again.

Comment: Thanks for your help Marcio. I fixed a touches began part but your code worked. Cheers